# Configuring a section alias in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, package-writing, xparse

Every week I produce a couple of A5 booklets (A4 folded) for my wife, an active colleague in church ministry, from which I am recently retired. I call the booklets a pulpit manuscript, as it includes the basic script of everything that is said or sung in the course of the service. Each part of the service is given a section, such as `\section{Prayer}`, `\section{Reading}`, etc. Each goes into the tableofcontents, so that inside the cover, I have the service running order at a glance. I have used various TeX approaches such as memoir, koma-script, ConTeXt, etc., and every editor available. I am settled on Auctex, using Spacemacs.

Although I have been using LaTeX for years, recently, I ventured into splitting my preamble into `.cls` and `.sty` files, which has all worked out fine for me. This inspired me to consider whether there might be some way in which I could save myself the tedium of writing this sort of thing every time I want to include a hymn in the order of service:

```
\section{\textbf{Hymn 360} \hfill \textit{\normalsize Praise, my soul}}
```

This results in **Hymn 360** *Praise, my soul*, which is pretty much what I want.

I tried the xparse package, which allows me to use

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\hymn}{mm}{\textbf{#1}{\hfill}\textit{#2}}
```

in the preamble, and then `\hymn{}{}` in the document. It looks pleasing enough, but, unfortunately, it does not go into the toc. (I know that I can use \addcontentsline, but that would be to make the shortcut longer than the route. I am trying to make life easier, not more complex.)

I have also tried `\let\hymn\section` and `\renewcommand{\hymn}{\section}`, which does put the hymn into the toc, but I do not know how to format the section in the text in a way that matches exactly what I have from xparse above. I am told that it is not a good idea to use an alias for `\section` but, in my use case, I do not foresee that as a problem.

I am wondering if someone could show me how to get a nicely formatted `\section` header from `\hymn{Hymn 360}{Praise, my soul}`. I like what xparse produces but I am not able to get it into the toc. When I make `\hymn` an alias for `\section`, I do not know how to format the section behind the scenes so that it produces **Hymn 360** *Praise, my soul*. Basically, I want to achieve that in such a way that for each new document, I do not need to make a lot of manual formatting.

I have tried to be painstakingly clear as to what I have tried, and what I want, but am happy to elaborate if required. In reality, I could get by as I do now with the `\section{\textbf{Hymn 360}` `\hfill` `\textit{\normalsize Praise, my soul}}` but I like to dream that there is a better way.

Comment: Why don't you just include the `\section` wrapper in the definition of `\hymn`?

Comment: Or put the adding to contents in the definition of `\hymn`. A proper minimum working example would encourage others to help you. That's much more useful than a fragment of code.

Comment: OK, I have made progress by adopting the first suggestion offered by @StevenB.Segletes. My nicely formatted hymn appears in the toc. However, it is no longer nicely formatted in the text, as the \section command causes the whole heading to be in bold rather than the first line of the hymn being in italics. It looks as I wish it in the toc.

Comment: How do I  upvote that first comment, please?

Comment: OK, as I was tidying up my document to prepare it as MWE, I realised that since I can now get 

    \usepackage{xparse}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\hymn}{mm}{\addsec{\textbf{#1}{\hfill}\textit{#2}}}

to both appear in my text and in the toc, my original question has been answered.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to have the \section heading to allow me to produce **Hymn 646**  *The day thou gavest* instead of **Hymn 646   The day thou gavest.** If that means that I have to ask the question in a different part of the forum, please let me know.

Comment: @cfr I opted to try putting \section wrapper in \hymn definition. That enabled me to progress to the point of changing the question 
as I have commented above.

Comment: By looking in other forums, I have learned that the font that I use must include an italic version, such as kpfonts. That has allowed me to do what I wanted. I now consider both my original question, and my supplementary one to have been answered.

Thanks for the advice from the two who commented, which helped me head towards a solution, as I have outlined above. I do not know if I am able to upvote or mark the question as answered, but, in any case, thanks.

Comment: In a case like this, you can post your solution as an answer (not a comment) and then accept it.  In such a case, it would help to include some small self-contained code so that other readers can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks,. @Steven. I shall get to it in the morning. It is 0018 here, and I am in bed.  Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the production of a booklet for my wife, who conducts church services more than once a week, I use a \section heading to mark each component of the service. For most components, this is straightforward enough. For instance: \section{Prayer}.

However, I like to add some formatting to the \section for a hymn so that it looks like: **Hymn 646**   *The day thou gavest*. As it is an A5 booklet, I like to make the text of the first line of the hymn fit, and then I use \normalsize to make the line take up less space.

Although it is hardly an inconvenience to format the hymn line in this way, I wondered if I could do this automatically, so that all I would need to do was put {} round the hymn number and also the first line, so that in the text I would write \hymn{Hymn 646}{The day thou gavest}, and LaTeX would look after the formatting. The other requirement was that the hymn should be listed in the \tableofcontents.

I discovered that the following code in the preamble would do what I wanted as far as formatting the \hymn heading was concerned. However, it did not appear in the toc.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hymn}{mm}{\textbf{#1}{\hfill}\textit{#2}}
```

It was put to me that I should "include the \section wrapper in the definition of hymn". As I use the documentclass scrbook by Koma-script, and did not want a numbered section, I used \addsec rather than \section. That resulting code was as shown below:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hymn}{mm}{\addsec{\textbf{#1}{\hfill}\textit{#2}}}
```

This worked in so far as it put the hymn into the toc. However, I lost the nice formatting of the \addsec heading in the text. The italics were gone! A little research revealed that I needed a font that had an italics version, such as kpfonts. I made that my font for the document, and, finally, I had achieved my goal.

Thanks to those who commented by suggesting steps I felt unable to take. After some thought, I realised what they were saying.  Should colleagues using LaTeX for service booklets find this answer of interest, I should be happy to hear from them.

Comment: "I use the documentclass scrbook ... so I should use \addsec rather than \section." That's not true. `\addsec` is a nice feature of KoMa classes which allows you to have unnumbered sections in the `toc`, but it's not a general replacement.

Comment: @campa, you are correct, and i have amended my answer accordingly. Thanks for drawing that to my attention.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you didn't try `\NewDocumentCommand{\hymn}{mm}{\section{\textbf{#1} \hfill \textit{\normalsize #2}}`.  Or maybe you did.